# Getting html table data other than text content (get "title" tag data)

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, html-table

One table entry within a table row on an html table I am trying to scrape looks like so:

```
<td class="top100nation" title="PAK">
<img src="/images/flag/flags_pak.jpg" alt="PAK"></td>
```

The web page to which this belongs is the following: http://www.relianceiccrankings.com/datespecific/odi/?stattype=bowling&day=01&month=01&year=2014. The entire column to which this belongs in the table has similar table data (i.e. it's a column of images).

I am using lxml in a python script. (Open to using BeautifulSoup instead, if I have to for some reason.) For every other column in the table, I can extract the data I want on the given row by using 'data = entry.text_content()'. Obviously, this doesn't work for this column of images. But I don't want the image data in any case. What I want to get from this table data is the 'PAK' bit - that is, I want the name of the nation. I think this is extremely simple but unfortunately I am a simpleton who doesn't understand the library he is using.

Thanks in advance

*Edit*: Full script, as per request

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import csv

with open('firstPageCricinfo','w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)

page = requests.get(url)

doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)

#rows of the table
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tr')

data_array = [[] for _ in range(len(tr_elements))]

del tr_elements[0]

for t in tr_elements[0]:
    name=t.text_content()
    if name == "":
            continue
    print(name)
    data_array[0].append(name)

#printing out first row of table, to check correctness
print(data_array[0])

for j in range(1,len(tr_elements)):
    T=tr_elements[j]

    i=0

    for t in T.iterchildren():

        #column is not at issue 
        if i != 3:
            data=t.text_content()
        #image-based column
        else:
            #what do I do here???
            data = t.

        data_array[j].append(data)
        i+=1

#printing last row to check correctness
print(data_array[len(tr_elements)-1])


with open('list1','w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    for i in range(0,len(tr_elements)):
        writer.writerow(data_array[i])`
```

Comment: Can you include what code you're using so far so we can see where to start?

Comment: Pretty sure the rest of the code is irrelevant but sure, I will post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with `lxml` library you'll either need to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) or some other library to get the website content.

Without seeing the code you have so far, I can offer a BeautifulSoup solution:

```
url = 'http://www.relianceiccrankings.com/datespecific/odi/?stattype=bowling&day=01&month=01&year=2014'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

r = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'top100cbr'})

for td in r:
    print(td.text.split('v')[1].split(',')[0].strip())
```

outputs about 522 items:

```
South Africa
India
Sri Lanka

...

Canada
New Zealand
Australia
England
```